# python: Multiple plotting in one subplot2grid-image

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let f be a function that depends on an independent variable x and on one (or more) parameter b.
My goal is to draw f for several values of b into the same image. And I want that b is a global value (so that I can quickly change it).
Consider the code

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

b=0.5
def f(x,b):
    return np.sin(x*b)*b

X = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
F = f(X,b)
pl.figure(figsize=(12, 16), num="My sine")
pl.plot(X, F, label='b = %f' %b)
pl.legend(loc="best")
```

This code can be evaluated multiple times, just with another value for b. Then all the curves are drawn into the same figure.

Now the problem:
If in the above code I put

```
pl.subplot2grid((4, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=3)
```

between `pl.plot` and `pl.legend`, every new evaluation of the code is drawn into a new blank figure.

So, how can I realise that with using `pl.subplot2grid` each evaluation is drawn into the same figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

def f(x,b):
    return np.sin(x*b)*b

def draw(b):
    X = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
    F = f(X,b)
    ax1.plot(X, F, label='b = %f' %b)


# Main program
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(12, 16), num="My sine")
ax1 = pl.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,0), colspan=2)

for b in [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]:
    draw(b)

pl.legend(loc="best")
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The good thing about your suggestion is, that indeed it draws all the curves into the same figure. However, if possible, I want to keep b a global value.

Comment: And the bad thing?

Comment: I would like to keep b a global, which isn't specified anywhere else like in the loop.

Comment: Maybe you can update your code with my code and show in more detail what you are looking for and how you call that routine? What stops you from defining fig and ax1 in your main routine and just plotting the new function to ax1 as I have done in the loop?

Comment: The code-snippet I showed above is part of a 1000-lines-long code with a lot of physics-functions and numerical staff. All these lines are stored in a .py-file and I write into and evaluate this file with the Pyzo-IDE. Somewhere at the beginning of the code the parameters, like b in my example, are specified. At the end of the code I have some functions that plot certain physics-functions. I usually have `def LookAtf():` and in the body of this I place the last 5 lines of the code-snippet above. Then I just select the body of `def LookAtf():` and click on "Evaluate selection" in Pyzo.

Comment: OK, but everything you are looking for should be in my code as far as I see. So where is the remaining problem?

Comment: @Chris if your file is big you should consider splitting it. You are basically in the case of writing a physics _module_ you are testing with plotting. Separate the function/physics stuff from the constants + plot functions (they should import the physics module), then you can play easily with values. I think tfv is doing it right there

Answer (score 0):

I did it now with a for-loop inside the LookAtf function, as you, tfv, recommended. Here is my result [image: My result]

However the legend still isn't doing as I want.
But anyway thanks for the hints!

@ Arthur Havlicek:
Actually my code is already divided into 3 parts. If the 3. part is evaluated, it automatically imports the 2. part, which again automatically imports the 1. part.
Actually, in my case, it is not possible to define the constants after the functions definition. The reason for this is that the way the functions are defined, depends on the choices of the constants. So, I first have to define the constants to let python know how it should define the functions.